# Tiff Output is not as expected for Black and white 1200dpi LZW test file created using Universal Document Converter 6.7 & 6.8 versions

Tags: tiff, smoothing, lzw, document-conversion

Respected Sir/Madam,

I have a doubt regarding LZW BW 1200dpi tiff file creation using “UDC driver 6.7/6.8 version”.

If we disable “'Perform High-Quality Smoothing”, then output data are not visible in output files.

If we enable this option, it is working fine.

Also, working fine for UDC driver 6.4 for both Enable/Disable 'Perform High-Quality Smoothing'.

We are using below tiff library version in our software.

/* Version number of package */
#define VERSION "4.0.3"

Could you please clarify our below doubts.

1. ```
     LZW support for 'Perform High-Quality Smoothing' always should be enabled?
   ```
2. ```
     Is this issue introduced in UDC driver version 6.7?
   ```

https://www.print-driver.com/overview/version-history

Best Regards,

Shantala R

Answer (score 0):

Please contact the developers of the software regarding their product.

https://www.print-driver.com/support

Comment: Thank you. Yes. I am discussing with support team on this.